# Golang channel didnt get closed

Tags: go, channel

i am quite new with go especially channel. i tried to close a channel but it didn't get closed thus making  method

```
fmt.Println("transaksi finaly done")
```

and

```
fmt.Println("order finaly done")
```

didn't get called by the program, what did i do wrong to exact?

full code

```
func (u *Usecase) GetOrderDetailByIDUsecase(ctx context.Context, orderId uint64) (*order.OrderPageDetailResponseDTO, error) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
    orderCh := make(chan *order.OrderResponseDTO)
    transaksiCh := make(chan *transaksi.TransaksiResponseDTO)
    errCh := make(chan error, 2)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("order start")
        orderResp, err := u.orderController.GetOrderByID(ctx, orderId)
        fmt.Println("order done")
        errCh <- err
        orderCh <- orderResp
        fmt.Println("transaksi finaly done")
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("transaksi start")
        transaksiResp, err := u.transaksiController.GetTransaksiByID(ctx, int64(orderId))
        fmt.Println("transaksi done")
        errCh <- err
        transaksiCh <- transaksiResp
        fmt.Println("transaksi finaly done")
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(errCh)
        close(orderCh)
        close(transaksiCh)
    }()
    
    for err := range errCh {
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    var orderResp *order.OrderResponseDTO
    var transaksiResp *transaksi.TransaksiResponseDTO
    select {
    case orderResp = <-orderCh:
    case transaksiResp = <-transaksiCh:
    }

    return &order.OrderPageDetailResponseDTO{
        Order:     orderResp,
        Transaksi: transaksiResp,
    }, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "producer" goroutines are blocked on  `orderCh` and `transaksiCh`.  Since you didn't give them a size in the call to `make`, the write will block until somebody is ready to read it.  The same goroutine that reads those channels waits for `errCh` to close, but that depends on the producer goroutines both finishing because of your `WaitGroup`.